# Display html string value on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, html, pandas, string, escaping

Say I have a dataframe with string values that contains some HTML

```py
my_dict = {"a":{"content":"""
<p>list of important things</p>
<ul>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
</ul>
"""}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict,orient='index')
```

The result is to be expected:

[image]

I'd like to export the dataframe as HTML such that my HTML string works inside the table cells.

#### What I've tried

I'm aware of `DataFrame.to_html(escape=False)`, which produces:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>content</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>\n<p>list of important things</p>\n<ul>\n<li>c</li>\n<li>d</li>\n</ul>\n</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

which looks wrong:

[image]

because that HTML has a literal `\\n`, so I think the method has taken the `repr` of the string value when inserting it into the HTML conversion of the dataset.

I **know** I could get away replacing the scaped `\\n` into `\n` again, which looks like it should:

[image]

But I'd like to know if there is some way to tell pandas to insert the literal string values of the dataframe into the HTML, not the `repr` ones. I don't understand half of the kwargs for `.to_html()`, so I don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to export the dataframe as HTML such that my HTML string
> works inside the table cells.

If so, you may want to consider replacing `\n` by HTML new line character ie. `<br>` if you want to get newline for it or you can just replace it by an empty string.

```py
df['content'] = df['content'].str.replace('\n', '<br>')
df.to_html('html.html', escape=False)
```

And if you don't want to replace the dataframe itself, you can let pandas handle it by passing it as a formatter:

```py
df.to_html('html.html', 
           formatters = {'content': lambda k: k.replace('\n', '<br>')}, 
           escape=False)
```

And if you just completely want to get rid of new line, you can just replace it by empty string, either in dataframe itself or passing as a formatter.

```py
df.to_html('html.html', 
           formatters = {'content': lambda k: k.replace('\n', '')}, 
           escape=False)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I could not find an explanation of how to use the formatters kwarg, but I think I understand it now